# How does hot cloning a running Windows drive actually work?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd, clone

I'm aware of the software options - what I mean is, how do they actually achieve this, when a running OS may be writing files such as logs, even if I try to not actively use it?

I read one comment that they may use something like Volume Shadow Copy which should at least create a consistent (non-corrupted) disk image, but I think without extra logic it could miss updates. Does it hook in at a lower level or schedule a task on shutdown/startup to finalise things?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm aware of the software options - what I mean is, how do they actually achieve this,

It depends on the specific software, but Volume Shadow Copy is likely the most common method; there are products that install their own filter driver (like how Veeam Backup has its "Changed Block Tracking").

Copying all files, then doing a final resync to pick up changes, could also be done (although doesn't provide a 100% consistent system but it can sometimes be Good Enough). This is also how VM live-migration is often implemented.

(Linux doesn't have universal snapshots, but it has the feature to freeze all write I/O to a filesystem; typically for brief moments while a LVM snapshot is made, but in theory it could be used to clone as well.)

> without extra logic it could miss updates

That's usually not a problem – generally you just don't do Important Work on the system while it's being cloned, so any missed changes would be minor (e.g. background updates that will restart on next boot, or log events pertaining to changes that didn't happen in the snapshot anyway). You wouldn't clone a production DB server this way.

Comment: This is roughly what I thought, but some tools seem to make a stronger promise that would mean not even the most minor changes won't be lost. Either way, the exact details are probably proprietary I guess.

Comment: That would likely be the "change tracking" format, where the tool does a quick resync after the initial clone is over.